# Is wearing a kippa as a non-believer okay?

Tags: kippa-yarmulka

After [an anti-Semitic attack](https://www.haaretz.com/world-news/europe/jewish-man-attacked-in-berlin-assailant-caught-on-video-1.6011973) against a man wearing a kippa in Berlin, Germany in April 2018, [over 2000 people gathered](https://www.haaretz.com/world-news/europe/berlin-jews-organize-wear-a-kippah-demonstration-in-response-1.6026552) for a "Wear a kippa" march in order to show solidarity.

> Germans of various faiths donned Jewish skullcaps and took to the streets Wednesday in several cities to protest an anti-Semitic attack in Berlin and express fears about growing hatred of Jews in the country.

That's obviously a great gesture done in, well, good faith. However, I was wondering if wearing a kippa as someone who is not a Jew is generally acceptable or if it could be perceived as offensive / inappropriate.